# Erlang on AIX 6

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, aix

I am about to use AMQP for a project and would like to use RabbitMQ, as it looks to be a good implementation. My problem is that one of the platforms will be AIX 6, and I cannot find a installable binary for the platform. Even worse it looks like there is no port of erlang for AIX.

Can anyone give me a pointer to erlang for AIX 6 or at least a port that I can compile without too much pain. Thanks...

Comment: Have you tried at all to build from source (http://www.erlang.org/download.html) on AIX 6? A quick googling on "erlang aix" indicates that people have at least on previous AIX versions (and older Erlang versions) managed to get it to work. E.g., http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2011-February/011425.html

Comment: I was going to do that but I think (maybe incorrectly) that the erlang scheduler is somewhat dependent on the hardware architecture. A web search only turned up people with AIX build errors asking questions, but no answers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that RabbitMQ is usually installed on one or more servers that are used exclusively for the MQ broker function? If you do it that way, perhaps you can justify some Linux or Solaris servers to run RabbitMQ.

If you can run a virtualization environment on AIX then a Linux or OpenSolaris VM would be the best way to go.

Comment: Yes I was aware of that, but one of the customers we sell to is a dedicated AIX house, and would take a dim view of us telling him to support another flavour of UNIX just so that he could use our product. I would also like to use Erlang for parts of the product, but the same problem applies, bummer.